# Is there an Applescript Error Log that tells you what the error numbers mean?

Tags: error-handling, applescript

Does anyone know if there Is there an Applescript Error Log that tells you what the error numbers mean?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Local Link to the list with error numbers/messages:

```
xcdoc://osx/documentation/AppleScript/Conceptual/AppleScriptLangGuide/reference/ASLR_error_codes.html
```

You can also use the command line utility `macerror`.

Here what the "man"ual page has to say (`man macerror`):

```
The macerror script translates Mac error numbers into their symbolic name and description.
```

How to use: open `Terminal.app` and type - for example -  `macerror -43` or any other error number.

Result: `Mac OS error -43 (fnfErr): File not found.`

Comment: That xcdoc: link wants to open XCode to resolve the URL and when it does I get an error message saying there is no handler registered.

Answer (score 5):

The authoritative list is hiding in one of the many .h files within the MacOS SDK, but Apple documentation also has a very handy & useful page as well.  I've attached the link below:

[Error Numbers and Error Messages](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/applescript/conceptual/applescriptlangguide/reference/ASLR_error_codes.html).