# The issue about importing variable into javascript in AppleScript

Tags: javascript, applescript

I meet an issue when I imported a variable（got from javascript A）to the javascript B, here is my script code:

```
tell application "Safari"
    tell tab 6 of window 1
        set varA to do JavaScript "document.getElementById('idA').textContent." as string
    end tell
    tell tab 7 of window 1
        do JavaScript "
        document.getElementById('idB').value=" & varA & ";"
    end tell
end tell
```

And I found when varA contains non-number content, it couldn't be imported to the input filed of "idB", I don't understand.....

I tried to return var A in AppleScript, it shows the value correctly. And I tried to

```
"set varB do JavaScript "
document.getElementById('idB').value=" & varA & ";"
```

When I return var B in AppleScript, it shows error number -2753.

I hope the script can help me to get the value from webpage A and input it to a specific input filed on webpage B.

Comment: You forgot to provide details of the outerHTML of the element selected by `#idB`. For readership, the link in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22285401/5217142) shows error code -2753 as "The variable <name> is not defined."

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if `varA` is not a number, you need to put quotes around the value in the assignment statement. Otherwise it will treat it as an expression to evaluate.

```
    tell tab 7 of window 1
        do JavaScript "
        document.getElementById('idB').value='" & varA & "';"
```

Not that if `varA` contains single quote or backslash characters, you'll need to escape them. See [Does AppleScript have a replace function?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38041852/does-applescript-have-a-replace-function) for ways to do text replacement in AppleScript.

Comment: Thanks bro! It works! That's too detailed!